# How to use parameters as object property?

Tags: php, javascript

In PHP we do it like this:

```
function($param)
{
     $this->{$param};
}
```

How can we do it in JavaScript?

Comment: `function(param) { this[param]; }`. Of course that's nonsensical without either returning the property, setting it, or calling it as a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know PHP but you could use square bracket notation to access properties.

```
function(param)
{
     this[param];
}
```

Comment: $scope[campaign_type].push(data); ?

Answer (score 1):

in javascript you can write like this

```
function House(rooms,price,garage) {
    this.rooms=rooms;
    this.price=price;
    this.garage=garage;
}
```